how to dynamically add row values to a string
In the below code, I expect row_values variable to be populated with actual values from row
but instead of its returning like "'{row.col1}',{'NULL' if row.col2  in ['NaT', None,''] else row.col2}"
Please check the code and let me know how to do it? Thank you!
The reason i stored all the row values in a string is that, it will be dynamic and i dont want to hard code it. Im planning to bring this row values columns from database.
`
insert_stmt="Insert into mytable(col1,col2)"
#
row_values ="'{row.col1}',{'NULL' if row.col2  in ['NaT', None,''] 
else row.col2}"
#
#the above row_values will come from SQL table but here i have hardcoded
#
data = {'col1': [1, 2, 3], 'col2': ['a', None, 'c'], 'col3': [4.5, 6.7, 'd']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#loop thro the dataframe
for row in df.itertuples(index=True):
    insert_stmt += f"{insert_stmt} values ( {row_values} \r\n"  
    print(insert_stmt)

output:
Insert into mytable(col1,col2) values ( '{row.col1}',{'NULL' if row.col2  in ['NaT', None,''] else row.col2}....
Please help

F-strings don't expand recursively. When it substitutes row_values, into insert_stmt, it doesn't process row_values as an f-string.

You should create a dataframe that contains the result of your conditions. Then you can use df.to_sql() to store it into a database.

can you give an example for this "You should create a dataframe that contains the result of your conditions. Then you can use df.to_sql() to store it into a database."

Something like df['col3'] = np.where(df['col2'.isin(['NaT', None, ''], df['col1'], df['col2']). I'm not a pandas/numpy expert, so this might not be the exactly correct syntax, but it gives the general idea.
